# Is System.out.println() completely compatible with Android?

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, incompatibility

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (i <= 3 || i% 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The output in LogCat is correct:

```
0
1
2
3
6
```

But when I change `System.out.println(i);` for `System.out.println("hi");` or any other object or number the output in LogCat is:

```
hi
hi
```

It should be a 5 x`hi` list. Is this a bug in Android or is it my system? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works fine in normal eclipse, hi is printed 5 times.

Comment: Maybe you are just unlucky and it is `hi hi hi something-else hi hi`.

Comment: Unfortunately `hi hi` is the last thing printed by LogCat after the `Showing myApp in 933ms` message.

Comment: run `adb logcat` from the console, that wont accidentally hide messages

Comment: If you put hi in the loop and add an extra sysout at the end/outside of loops, then what happens?

Comment: It is solved now, I ran `adb logcat` from the console and it showed everything. Zapl, please post it as an answer to mark it as accepted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println() is compatible with Android. Im not sure what you are doing, but when I run the code you gave I get the following outputs:

```
(System.out.println("hi");)
06-29 20:42:43.645: hi
06-29 20:42:43.645: hi
06-29 20:42:43.645: hi
06-29 20:42:43.645: hi
06-29 20:42:43.645: hi

(System.out.println(i);)

06-29 20:44:00.380: 0
06-29 20:44:00.380: 1
06-29 20:44:00.380: 2
06-29 20:44:00.380: 3
06-29 20:44:00.380: 6
```

I believe its a bug in either your system or the version of Android you are running. I can tell you the output above was running on API 15.

Comment: I'm using API 17, also de Log.i() method fails, I'll dig in and see what I can do. Thank you very much.